# How can I check that the page was loaded with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for a way to check that the page was loaded using Selenium. So basically does the url point to a correct address (in chrome the browser shows something like this) :
[image]

I am using the following code:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "SomeUrl";
```

Currently I am comparing the title to "SomeUrl is not available" and if it matches I mark that the page has failed to load.

But is there a better way?

Comment: That's the best way.  Its fast, and readable, and unless a webpage sets it title as such, won't fail.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, if you know what control ID/or link or/Class is going to appear on your page. Then wait for that element to appear on screen for a defined period of time.

I that element appears then your next line of code will be executed

Here is the simple version of m method. You can make it more dynamic based on your need.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// WaitForElementOnPage() method waits a passed number of seconds for the existence
    /// of a passed IWebElement object. If the object is found the method return an IWebElement of the object
    /// If the object is not found in the passed number of seconds, the method returns a null IWebElement
    /// </summary>

    public IWebElement WaitForElementOnPage(string controlID, int waitTime)
    {
        IWebElement element = null;
        IWebElement elementFound = null;

        try
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime));

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            elementFound = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
            {

                        element = d.FindElement(By.Id(controlID));
                        break;



                return element;

            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                        
            Log.Error(ex);
            elementFound = null;
        }

        return elementFound ;
    }
```

Comment: what if I don't?

Answer (score 0):

I personally try to locate `body` or `frameset` element on the page.

Based on my experience while using selenium with chromedriver, page content sometimes doesn't show up and I need to run `webdriver.refresh()` 1-2 times. It doesn't happen all the time, but I run big amount of chrome instances on one machine and this approach was the most effective for now to avoid this.

So I try to locate `body` or `frameset` elements and reload few times before I give up.

The advantage of this solution is also the fact that it will also work in case Chrome changes its messages in the future. It will also work with other browsers.